# How can I extract bits in Risc v assembly code

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, bit-fields, riscv

Register x5 stores 0x00C0_C000, register x6 stores 0x0000_C0000. At this time, you want to extract the value of bit [15:8] of thte register x5 and put it in the bit [31:16] of the register x6,. Complete the RISC-V assembly code to do this. However, the other bits of x5 and x6 should not change.

Replace the x6 [31:16] bit with the 8bit of [15:8] in the x5 register, but align the 8bit with the lower bit of the [31:16] bit.

I thought I should use `slli` and `srli` to extract bit. But using them, the other bit of x5 and x6 changes. How can I extract bits without changing other bits?

Comment: `0x0000_C0000` has 9 hex digits, 36 bits, if those zeros are all actually present.  I assume you meant some other value.  Anyway, have you considered how you'd do it in C?  Or just look at C compiler output for a struct with bit-field members?  You can of course shift into a different register like `unsigned tmp = x6 >> 16;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is:
Clearing the high part of x6 if it is not sure it is all the time equal to 0. You can do it with a mask :

```
li x28,0xffff
and x6,x6,x28
```

or

```
slli x6,x6,16
srli x6,x6,16
```

Since you cannot modify x5, you need to use an other tmp register:

```
mv x28,x5
```

get the 8 from [15:8] bits and place them in [31:16]

```
srli x28,x28,8
andi x28,x28,0xff
slli x28,x28,16
```

and finally you do an or to place these bits in x6:

```
or x6,x6,x29
```

Try also to take a look to https://raw.githubusercontent.com/riscv/riscv-bitmanip/master/bitmanip-0.90.pdf. RISC-V Bitmanip Extension can be interesting if it is supported.

Answer (score 0):

I would offer a next solution,i am using 0x00debc00 for easier viewing:
For RV64I

```
lui a1,0xDEB     # loads 0x00deb of 0x00debc00
li a2,0xC00      # loads 0xc00 of 0x00debc00
add a1,a1,a2     # stick together 0x00deb + c00 = 0x00debc00
slli a3,a1,48    # took 0x00de"bc"00 and moves to left corner to clean unnecessary bits
srli a4,a3,48    # move "bc" back into 0xbc00
xor a1,a1,a4     # use 0xbc00 for masking initial 0x00debc00 and get 0x00de0000
srli a3,a3,32    # move 0xbc from left corner of $a3 to it's place 0x0000bc00
add a1,a1,a3     # concatenate it all - voila! 0xbcde0000
```

maybe simpler, but I'm not a magician yet)

For RV32I you just should less shifting to the left:

```
lui a1,0xDEB
li a2,0xC00
add a1,a1,a2
slli a3,a1,16
srli a4,a3,16
xor a1,a1,a4
#srli a3,a3,32 no need to move back its already in it's place
add a1,a1,a3
```

Sorry for "Engrish".

Comment: You don't need separate lui/li, just use `li a1, 0x00debc00`.  `li` is a pseudo-instruction that will assemble to `lui` + `addi` (or just one or the other if one part is all zero).  Or if you want to do it manually, `lui a1,0xDEB` / `addi a1, a1, 0xc00`  (But note that `addi a1, a1, 0xc00` isn't truly encodeable: the 12-bit immediate field is *sign* extended to register width, but 12-bit `0xc00` has its top bit set; look at disassembly output for `li a1, 0x00debc00` to see what happens: adjust the top part up by 1 to compensate.)

Comment: i know about addi, that's why i'm not used it. Thanks for advice, i will try better now.

Comment: Ok, right, lost track of where I was going with that comment.  I should have just said `li a2,0xC00` itself already takes 2 instructions on its own (because it doesn't fit in 12-bits sign extended), so you might as well have just done `li a1, 0x00debc00`.  Simpler way to make the same point.  Also probably good to separate that input-setup from the bitfield-extract with at least a blank line, so it's clear which part is input and which part is the actual answer.